# Getting selected value from a dropdown using js

Tags: javascript, html, select

What am I doing wrong in this?

```js
var el = document.getElementById('option');
el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  room()
}, false);
var roomOption = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
```

```html
<select id="option">
  <option value = "1">Option 1</option>
  <option value = "2">Option 2</option>
  <option value = "3">Option 3</option>
  <option value = "4">Option 4</option>
  <option value = "5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is the `room` function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You room function were undefined .get the selected value from room functoin inside

```js
var el = document.getElementById('option');
el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  room()
}, false);
function room(){
var roomOption = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(roomOption)
}
```

```html
<select id="option">
            <option value = "1">Option 1</option>
            <option value = "2">Option 2</option>
            <option value = "3">Option 3</option>
            <option value = "4">Option 4</option>
            <option value = "5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create the "room" function, and your code will work, as the snippet.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('option');
el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  room()
}, false);
//var roomOption= el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;

function room() {
  var roomOption = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(roomOption);
}
```

```html
<select id="option">
            <option value = "1">Option 1</option>
            <option value = "2">Option 2</option>
            <option value = "3">Option 3</option>
            <option value = "4">Option 4</option>
            <option value = "5">Option 5</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: You can change `function() { room() }` to just `room` right?

Comment: @Arg0n My fault, revised.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your event handler do this

```
el.addEventListener('change', function(evt){ 
    var e = evt.target
    var id = e[e.selectedIndex].value; // now use it as you like...
    room(id);    //invoke room with id
}, false)
```